# Aframe glTF not displaying

Tags: javascript, aframe, gltf

I am testing a-frame and trying to load other glTF file(s) that not the examples provided in the tutorial.
I have downloaded a couple of glTF packs files from Sketchfab and they don't seem to load.

It works if I use aframes given link to file: 
https://cdn.aframe.io/test-models/models/virtualcity/VC.gltf

but not the ones I've downloaded from Sketchfab.
The path to the file is correct — I have an **assets** folder next to my index.html which in turn contains **perseus_fighting_medusa** folder, which in turn contains the glTF, glb and textures folder. 
I'm getting this error message a bunch of times.

[image]

What am I not getting here?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>glTF Model - A-Frame School</title>
    <meta name="description" content="glTF Model - A-Frame School">
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/aframevr/aframe/b395ea0/dist/aframe-master.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>
        <a-assets>
            <a-asset-item id="cityModel" src="assets/perseus_fighting_medusa/scene.gltf"></a-asset-item>
        </a-assets>
        
        <a-gltf-model src="#cityModel" ></a-gltf-model>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hard to tell without being able to look at the model. Share a link with example to reproduce. glitch.com/~aframe is a good option. Verify that the model loads in the [gltf-viewer](https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/). If it doesn't the problem is in the model. Also use a recent A-Frame version. You're in an old one. <script src="aframe.io/releases/0.9.1/aframe.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update to A-Frame v0.9.1. `<script src="aframe.io/releases/0.9.1/aframe.min.js"></script>`